# Create Nested JSON out of PySpark Dataframe

Tags: json, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, nested

This flat json to nested json in pyspark.

```
{
    'event_type': 'click', 
    'id': '223',
    'person_id': 201031940, 
    'category': 'Chronicles', 
    'approved_content': 1
}
```

to

```
{
    'event_type': 'click', 
    user: {
        'id': '223',
        'person_id': 201031940
    },
    event: {
        'category': 'Chronicles', 
        'approved_content': 1
    }
}
```

Comment: add user key. add event key. call each value after event type. remove those key value pairs. insert the called key value pairs into the added keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

1. Define a schema, and convert flat json to dataframe using schema.
2. Register couple of UDFs to build user and event map.
3. Add new columns (user and event) in dataframe using UDFs register in #2
4. Drop the extra columns

Here is the complete code:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import (
    StringType,
    StructField,
    StructType,
    MapType
)
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

events_schema = StructType([
    StructField('event_type', StringType(), True),
    StructField('id', StringType(), True),
    StructField('person_id', StringType(), True),
    StructField('category', StringType(), True),
    StructField('approved_content', StringType(), True),
])

events = [{
    'event_type': 'click',
    'id': '223',
    'person_id': 201031940,
    'category': 'Chronicles',
    'approved_content': 1
}]
df = spark.createDataFrame(events, schema=events_schema)

build_user_udf = udf(lambda id, person_id: {
    'id': id,
    'person_id': person_id
}, MapType(StringType(), StringType()))

build_event_udf = udf(lambda category, approved_content: {
    'category': category,
    'approved_content': approved_content
}, MapType(StringType(), StringType()))

nested_event_df = (
    df
    .withColumn('user', build_user_udf(df['id'], df['person_id']))
    .withColumn('event', build_event_udf(df['category'], df['approved_content']))
    .drop('id')
    .drop('person_id')
    .drop('category')
    .drop('approved_content')
)
```

> nested_event_df.toJSON().first()
>
> '{"event_type":"click","user":{"id":"223","person_id":"201031940"},"event":{"approved_content":"1","category":"Chronicles"}}'
>
> nested_event_df.take(1)
>
> [Row(event_type='click', user={'id': '223', 'person_id': '201031940'}, event={'approved_content': '1', 'category': 'Chronicles'})]

This is quite basic version, but you can do more optimization if you would like.

Comment: Wonderful, this is what I was looking for. Minor thing, can I get the fields inside the nested columns to be in their individual quotes and not for the values

Comment: We need to apply the type while registering UDF's - I made the necessary changes and updated code snippet.

Answer (score 3):

you can also do it without the use of udfs which is more efficient, and significantly makes a difference if you're working with large number of records:

```
import pyspark.sql.fuctions as f
events_schema = StructType([
    StructField('event_type', StringType(), True),
    StructField('id', StringType(), True),
    StructField('person_id', StringType(), True),
    StructField('category', StringType(), True),
    StructField('approved_content', StringType(), True),
])

events = [{
    'event_type': 'click',
    'id': '223',
    'person_id': 201031940,
    'category': 'Chronicles',
    'approved_content': 1
}]
df = spark.createDataFrame(events, schema=events_schema)
newDf = (df
          .withColumn('user', f.struct(df.id, df.person_id))
          .withColumn('event', f.struct(df.category, df.approved_content))
          .withColumn('nestedEvent', f.struct(f.col('user'), f.col('event')))
          .select('nestedEvent'))
```